# Having a table of properties of an object and a table of conditions to make an action, how to query what action can an object do?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's suppose we have two tables (in this case in PostgreSQL).
The first one represents a many to many relationship between objects and properties, for every object there will be a row for every property it has:

```
CREATE Table objects(
id serial,
object_name text,
property text  
);
```

The second table represents a many-to-many relationship between actions and properties that an object must have to take them.

```
CREATE Table actions(
id serial,
action_name text,
property text  
);
```

How to write a query that, given an object name, returns all the actions that that object can do?

For example, given table objects as:

| id | object_name | property |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | object1 | can_swim |
| 2 | object1 | no_fear |
| 3 | object2 | can_swim |

and table actions

| id | action_name | property |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | scuba_dive | can_swim |
| 2 | scuba_dive | no_fear |
| 3 | waterpolo | can_swim |

If I want to know what action can object1 do I should get `scuba_dive` and `waterpolo` as answers, while object2 can only do `waterpolo`

Comment: Could you add some data examples and expected result in text format ?

Comment: Your second table is a duplicate of the first.

Answer (score 1):

Try with your data and let me know:

```
   select object_name,action_name
from (  select object_name,string_agg(property,',') as objects_property
         from  ( select object_name,property 
                 from objects
                 order by object_name,property  desc 
                ) as tt1
         group by object_name 
     ) as t1 
inner join 
    (   select action_name,string_agg(property,',') as action_property
        from  ( select action_name,property
                from actions 
                order by action_name,property desc 
              )as tt2
        group by action_name
    ) as t2 on t1.objects_property LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.action_property, '%')
where object_name='object1' ;
```

[Check Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a23674feb6b545fdc4a5ffdea12ed88b)

Comment: This depends on the order of insertion, if you swap the first two insertions in table objects it will break

Comment: @VariabileAleatoria could you reproduce an example in the fiddle ?

Comment: The concatenation depends on the order of the rows in the table 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=224fce1a31597abcec9dc0c3f89a221e

Comment: @VariabileAleatoria I updated my answer  forcing an order condition, try now and let me know

Comment: This doesn't work as soon as an object has an additional attribute which in alphabetical order is between two properties needed for an action

see [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a23674feb6b545fdc4a5ffdea12ed88b)